# Facebook App Login - Exchanging code for an oauth access token is working only once

Tags: facebook, authentication, token, access-token, facebook-login

I'm using the URL below to get the auth token:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=RETURN_URL&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream`

This page will redirect to another URL with the `code` token in query string. I'm using this `code` token to get the Page access token automatically and publish to the Page 'offline'.

In recent days, it seems that Facebook has changed the expiration time of this token `code`.

I am able to use this token once. The time expiration is very short. Anyone know if there really was a change in facebook? Is there any other alternative to work with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was part of the December 5th changes on the [Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/): the `code` can only be exchanged for an `access_token` once and must be exchanged within 10 minutes of generation.

> **New security restrictions for OAuth authorization codes**  We will only
>   allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once and
>   will require that they be exchanged for an access token within 10
>   minutes of their creation. This is in line with the OAuth 2.0 Spec
>   which from the start has stated that "authorization codes MUST be
>   short lived and single use". For more information, check out our
>   Authentication documentation.

If you're unsure how to log users in correctly because you were relying on the old, incorrect behaviour, ensure you're using the newest SDKs and read the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) documentation in detail, specifically the [Server Side Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) documentation which shows how to exchange the code for a token

Once you have the token, save it using whatever session storage mechanism your app uses (PHP SDK will store it in a PHP session for you) and use the access token on subsequent calls instead of trying to obtain a new `access_token` from the `code`